# npm run build | hash stamp to switch to date stamp

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, npm-scripts, npm-run

The npm run build command creates hash files
For example: 2.777d1846.chunk.css
The hash appears in the middle: 777d1846

I want to replace the hash with a date stamp for example: 20230614
I made a script in react that runs in post build and replaces the names of the files and it works very well now the files are: 2.20230614.chunk.css

But the source code is still looking for the file hash...
I need to find a way that the npm run build will also pre-build files with a date signature and also write them in the code as it does normally, only it needs to be configured not to use a hash but a date stamp.

btw: I don't have webpack config